How to get username from Application claims in Azure B2C
We have a user policy that I like the get username from loggin user.
Our user policy as only Signin and not signup. We are creating user from in the Azure B2C.
Feels little over kill to create a custom policy just to get username?

This is not about programming and is therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow (you can see what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]). You might have better luck on our sibling site, [sf].

Username is not a standard user attribute.
Two ways I can think of:

Run a script to move the username into an extension attribute that you can configure in the flow

Use a custom policy



I did end up creating a custom policy. Thanks for your help
